# What is Airdrop and how does it different from ICO?

Tags: airdrops, ico

I'd like to understand what's Airdrop and how does it different from Initial Coin Offering (ICO). Ideally in some general way.

Here are some example contexts:

- > **The tokens will not be distributed as initial coin offering (ICO) but rather as an airdrop.** "IQ Tokens will be **airdropped** into the EOS distribution list in late February," Forselius, told to Inverse in February 2018. Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everipedia#Blockchain).
- > Blockchain-based encyclopedia startup Everipedia announced plans to distribute its IQ tokens in June **through an "Airdrop" instead of taking the Initial Coin Offering (ICO) route**. The move would probably help bypass increasing regulatory hitches for ICOs. [Source](http://www.rttnews.com/2874727/wikipedia-rival-everipedia-announces-june-token-airdrop.aspx)

Comment: This question seems to be broadly about blockchain financing and token distribution in general, and not about EOS specifically.  This question would seem to be best suited for general blockchain/ICO related Stack Exchange.

Comment: There is no general blockchain site, the one that was, got [closed](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/106592/blockchain-technology) few days ago.

Comment: I agree that this isn't' very EOS specific, however, I've failed to find an appropriate stack exchange community for it to go to...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An airdrop is a **free** token distribution while a ICO is a fund offering in exchange of tokens. 
Everipedia wanted to do a ICO in order to collect funds to finance their project, then Block.One made a deal with the Everipedia team by funding their financial needs and it return they build on EOS and airdrop their tokens to eos token holders.

Answer (score 2):

Airdropping a token distribution to a widely distributed token distribution such as EOS can be beneficial for bootstrapping a project with a community that has an interest in the project. It also allows other projects to take advantage of the anti-consolidation properties of EOS, and achieve a more optimal distribution for their own project.